# Paypal and PHP, using CURL and NVP method : errno 10054

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, php-curl

I have developped functions to use PayPal NVP method for a website (I still use the Paypal Sandbox). All was working perfectly but since a week I can't make a request (setExpressCheckout), I have always an errcode 10054.
Here is the CURL log :

---

```
Trying 173.0.82.83...
Connected to api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.83) port 443 (#0)
Cipher selection: TLSv1
successfully set certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:\data\pem\cacert.pem
CApath: none
SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-SHA
Server certificate:
subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
start date: 2016-01-14 00:00:00 GMT
expire date: 2018-01-14 23:59:59 GMT
issuer: C=US; O=Symantec Corporation; OU=Symantec Trust Network; CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
SSL certificate verify ok.
GET /nvp?VERSION=124.0&USER=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&PWD=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&SIGNATURE=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&CANCELURL=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&RETURNURL=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Panier&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=100&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Panier&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=96.20&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=96.20&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR&DESC=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&LOCALECODE=FR&USERACTION=COMMIT&BRANDNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
User-Agent: PayPal-PHP-SDK
Accept: */*

SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
Closing connection 0
```

---

The SSL connection seems ok, but I have always this error.
I tried from a Windows server and a Linux server (both with Apache) with same results.

I really don't know how to solve my problem ...

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

PS:sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do you not get an error message with the error code?

Comment: Nothing found there : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errors/

Comment: probably using an old and bugged version of the SSL library (most likely OpenSSL), and you're hitting an ssl lib bug. - update your ssl lib (probably OpenSSL) and try again? i use PayPal Express Checkout just fine with php-curl, OpenSSL/1.0.2l LibCurl/7.52.1 PHP/7.0.19

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decided to rewrite my module using Soap. All is working now.